# Use Show to Display an Arbitrary Number of Objects

Tags: graphics, regions

(As always, feel free to inform me on how I can better ask questions if my formatting isn't preferred)

Just to use an arbitrary case, say I have a function in Mathematica

`cylinder[i_]:=RegionPlot3D[x^2+y^2 <= 1 && i-1 <= z <= i, {x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,0,10}];`

And say I don't know what `i` should be yet other than it will be an integer between 1 and 10. How would I use the `Show` function to display an unknown number of the cylinder functions?

My attempt at a solution came in the form

`n=5(*User defines n*); Show[For[j=1,j<=n,j++,cylinder[j]]]`

Comment: why not do `Show[cylinder[#] & /@ Range[1, n]]` ?  `For` loops are not recommended in Mathematica :)  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwlFE.png)

Comment: This works with my code! Although, can you explain the code in English? I am unsure what `& /@` is supposed to represent specifically.

Comment: it is a map command, same as writing `Show[Map[cylinder[#] &, Range[1, n]]]`  you are _mapping_ or _applying_ your function to Range 1 to n. So instead of applying the function one by one in a loop as you were doing, you can use `map` and it is done automatically for you.

Comment: I'll definitely need to re-read this a couple times, but I appreciate your time explaining!!

Comment: The map command is one of the most used commands in Mathematica. If you have function `f[x]` and want to apply it on list of values `{1,2,3,4}` one by one, then you can use Map for this. Just look up help on Mathematica Map and you'll see many examples.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific example, multiple cylinders can be included in a single [`RegionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

cylinder[i_] := 
 RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && i - 1 <= z <= i, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 10}]

Manipulate[
 RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 &&
   Or @@ ((# - 1 <= z <= #) & /@ cyl),
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 10},
  PlotPoints -> 75,
  MaxRecursion -> 4],
 {{cyl, {1,5,9}, "cylinders"},
  (# -> (# - 1 <= z <= #)) & /@ Range[10],
  ControlType -> CheckboxBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: May be a bit much for my use case, but definitely great study material to better use Mathematica in the future! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You already have a function that takes a single integer, and you want a function that applies that function to a range of integers. This is a perfect fit for Array:

```
cylinders[n_] := Array[cylinder, n]
```

This, of course, gives a list. You can wrap it in Show:

```
Show[cylinders[3]]
```

to keep cylinders independent of display, or you could make Show part of the definition if you don't need that independence:

```
cylinders[n_] := Show[Array[cylinder, n]]
```

Comment: This worked with my code! Thank you so much!